# Macro expansion - argument not replaced by define

Tags: c++, c, macros

Is there a way to use a `#define` as the parameter of a macro which is expanded?

Consider this example:

```
#define FOO BAR
#define USE_FOO(the_foo, fooinator) void do_use_foo_ ## the_foo()\
{ std::cout << #the_foo << fooinator << std::endl;}

USE_FOO(FOO, "baz")
```

The `USE_FOO(FOO, "baz)` expands to

```
void do_use_foo_FOO () {
std::cout << "FOO" << "baz" << std::endl;}
```

while I would have expected (and wanted) it to expand to

```
void do_use_foo_BAR () {
std::cout << "BAR" << "baz" << std::endl;}
```

with the FOO being defined as BAR at the top. What am I missing and is there a way to achieve what I expect?

Comment: You need two levels of macros to stringify the result of expansion of a macro argument. See the [preprocessor docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html).

Comment: Yeah, stop using macros...